# Django rest framework: serializer does not include id field in response data

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am learning Django rest framework and have created the following serializer:

```
class EventCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
organiser = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

class Meta:
    model = Event
    fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'date', 'organiser']

def save(self, **kwargs):
    name = self.validated_data['name']
    description = self.validated_data['description']
    date = self.validated_data['date']
    organiser = self.data['organiser']
    organiser_account = Account.objects.get(username=organiser)

    if not organiser_account:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Error setting the organiser field')

    event = Event.objects.create(name=name, description=description, date=date, organiser=organiser_account)
    event.save()
    return event
```

Notice how 'id' is included as a field.

Now I have the following view:

```
class EventCreateView(APIView):
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

def post(self, request, format=None):
    context = {
        'request': self.request
    }
    serializer = EventCreateSerializer(data=request.data, context=context)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data,
                        status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    return Response({'fail': serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

So when I make a post request to the appropriate url, I get back a response that include serializer.data. However, this does not contain the 'id' field (but it does contain the other fields).

The model used has an automatically generated id field.

I want the response to include the id field, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an Event instance by doing `serializer.save()` . Later you are returning the response. Here `serializer.data` won't include the `id` of the instance created because you have invoked `def save(self, **kwargs)` function, which just returns those fields which were used while creating an instance (meaning `id` isn't used and is auto generated).

Instead, you can save the instance when you use save(), like below:
`instance = serializer.save()`

later save the serializer data in a variable:
`response_data = serializer.data`

and now add the `id` field:
`response_data['id'] = instance.id`

and return `response_data`